# parse.com anypic, first time using it and having an error.

Tags: objective-c, many-to-many, parse-platform

well, I have Just download anypic from the Parse.com site or from the github if you like.
I want to open the files and exploring them to see how it's work , the problem is , the first time i'm running it i'm getting an error on these 4 lines

```
static NSUInteger const kPAPCellFollowTag = 2;
static NSUInteger const kPAPCellNameLabelTag = 3;
static NSUInteger const kPAPCellAvatarTag = 4;
static NSUInteger const kPAPCellPhotoNumLabelTag = 5;
```

the error state 
/Users/Anypic-master/Anypic-iOS/Anypic/PAPFindFriendsViewController.m:32:25: Unused variable 'kPAPCellAvatarTag'
and the same goes for Label,Tag,PhoneNumLabel ...
it's very odd that this is the first time i'm running it and i'm getting this error , is there any way to fix this , so i can run it on my simulator without an error ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an error, but rather warnings, and you should be able to run the app with them. Try commenting out those lines.

Comment: I did it , but i'm getting this error : ParsePlatform-Anypic-7ba4fbf/Anypic-iOS/Resources/Default-fb231265150320768-568h@2x.png: No such file or directory

Comment: This is another error. Seems to be something wrong with possibly the default launch image. It should be "Default-568h@2x.png", not that long string. I also get this, but it is a warning, not an error. Although here it looks for the filename I quoted above. You should see this warning in Xcode, where you can click it and you get the option that xcode can add it for you.

Comment: thank you for the answer, what i did is download the project again ( delete the old one ) and then Xcode asking to perform some changes, I enable it , and then having a new ( but only one ) error : /Users/guycohen/Downloads/Anypic-master-2/Anypic-iOS/Anypic/PAPActivityFeedViewController.m:153:98: Undeclared selector 'isParseReachable' <------ ( the error is at the PAPPhotoTimelineViewController.m )

Answer (score 0):

well I wrote to parse team and this is the Answer i got from them 
"The current source code for Anypic is known to compile in Xcode 4.6. The warnings you are seeing are due to deprecated methods introduced in iOS 7 and Xcode 5. There's no ETA for a fix yet, but it should be pretty straightforward (the warnings tell you what needs to be changed). " 
what's going on with them ? xcode 5 is been out there for long time now... I hope theres going to be a fix, and i hope I helped anyone.

Comment: You are still talking about warnings, not errors, right? I have no problems compiling and running Anypic with xcode 5 (although I do get warnings).

Comment: No ! I'm getting an errors , the red annoying ones which I can't get to run the program ..:-)